# How to enlarge the clip of Swing Graphics2D set by the RepaintManager

Tags: java, swing, clip, repaintmanager

I'm stuck with Swing repaint management. I would like to blur the background of a component. I use a BufferedImage to capture and blur stuff covered by my component. On paintComponent() I paint the blured image as background.

Everything works fine if the component is repainted entirely but I cannot overcome problems in the following scenario:

- A component is covered by my component but does not overlap completely
- Before the repaint is executed, a clip (subregion covering the occluded component) is set by the RepaintManager restricting changes to the graphics object
- setting/clearing a user clip always intersects with this clip region
- creating a new graphics object is always a copy or intersects this clip region
- Because the image I want to paint is blured, I have to draw pixels outside the clip set by the RepaintManager

How can I make sure that the component can paint all of its pixels on paintComponent() regardless of the clip set by the RepaintManager?

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE/MCTRE, short runnable, compilable, with creating image from void, class

Comment: @mKorbel  Ugh..  The MCTaRE (which I was getting used to), is now back to being an MCVE.  I'm not sure if I mentioned to you, but the SSCCE has now found a new (hopefully stable/permanent) home at Java Ranch.  Given it was edited down (by me) before going there, I am tempted to switch back to linking to it (@ sscce.org).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson aaaaaaach ....., what to say

Comment: Of course runnable code can help alot to demonstrate the problem. I will provide code with my next question thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Meanwhile I found a solution which seems to work fine for me. I subclassed RepaintManager to check whether a dirty component is occluded by the blured one. If that is the case, I merge their bounds and traverse the parents until the new bounds are comletely contained. Finally I schedule the dirty region and the found component for repaint. I'am not exactly happy with the solution because I have to provide a new RepaintManager which effects all repaint calls.